# node.js. Problems saving requested zip file to disk

Tags: node.js

I'm having trouble saving a remote zip file to disk with with node.
I'm using `request` library to make requests.  I want to request a zip file, 
if the request is succesful write it to disk. I can't get a good combination of 
correct error handling and writing the file.

I want to do the following :

```
request.get('https://example.com/example.zip', {
    'auth': { 'bearer': accessToken },
}, function(error, response, body) {
  // shortcircuit with notification if unsuccessful request
  if (error) { return handleError() }
    // I want to save to file only if no errors
    // obviously this doesn't work because body is not a stream
    // but this is where I want to handle it.
    body.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./output.zip'));
});
```

I know I can pipe the request directly as follows but I can't get decent error handling. The on error callback doesn't fire for 404s, and if I catch the request and throw an error if `!response.ok` the empty output file is still written to disk

```
  request.get('https://example.com/example.zip', {
    'auth': { 'bearer': accessToken },
  })
  .on('error', handleError)
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./output.zip'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `body.pipe()`, use `response.pipe()`.

```
request.get('https://example.com/example.zip', {
  auth: {
    bearer: accessToken
  }
}, (err, res, body) => {
  if (res.statusCode !== 200) { // really should check 2xx instead
    return handleError();
  }
  res.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./output.zip');
});
```

The downside here though is that the request module is going to buffer the full response.  Easy fix... don't use the request module.  `http.get()` is fine and is a drop-in replacement.

Also, I highly recommend checking out the [request-promise module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) which has an option for failing on 404.